# Generate-pch command failed when embedding Unity to Swift Project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I have a Unity app which uses Vuforia. I'm trying to embed this Unity app within a Swift Project. I am following the guide given here [Integrating Unity Project into Xcode Swift Project](https://github.com/jiulongw/swift-unity). However when I build the project I get this error:

```
<unknown>:0: error: generate-pch command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1
```

This is my `Bridging-Header.h` file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#ifndef BRIDGING_HEADER
#define BRIDGING_HEADER

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "UnityUtils.h"
#import "UnityAppController.h"
#import "UnityInterface.h"

#endif /* BRIDGING_HEADER */
```

This is my project structure:

[image]

My xcode Version is 9.2 and Unity Version is 2017.3.1f1

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?